# How can I efficiently use HealthKit's step count functionality within a Flutter app?

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, healthkit

I'm doing research for an app I have to build for our start-up.

I want to build an app that keeps count of the steps a person takes every day by using HealthKit on iOS.

When the user requests a refresh or restarts the app, I can request the latest step count available. However, we want to push notifications to the user as soon as they have taken a set amount of steps (10,000 for example).
So I was wondering if I could set up a listener within flutter, so that HealthKit would (battery efficiently) provide the latest step count as they come in or at a set value/interval.

Is this 'listener'-architecture that communicates between flutter and native Swift code possible with flutter, and if so, is it the best approach?
Is the same also possible on the Android side?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit)'s or [HKObserverQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobserverquery) is what you need on the iOS side

> Receiving Background Deliveries
>
> Apps can also register to receive updates while in the background by
>   calling the HealthKit store’s
>   enableBackgroundDelivery(for:frequency:withCompletion:) method. This
>   method registers your app for background notifications. HealthKit
>   **wakes your app whenever new samples of the specified type are saved to
>   the store.** Your app is called at most once per time period defined by
>   the frequency you specified when registering.

As for architectures that

> communicates between flutter and native Swift code ... Is the same
>   also possible on the Android

I believe you are looking for [Flutter Platform Channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) where you can find a [Swift Example](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/#example-swift).

> **Flutter uses a flexible system that allows you to call
>   platform-specific APIs whether available in Java or Kotlin code on
>   Android, or in ObjectiveC or Swift code on iOS.**
>
> Flutter’s platform-specific API support does not rely on code
>   generation, but rather on a flexible message passing style:
>
> The Flutter portion of your app sends messages to its host, the iOS or
>   Android portion of your app, over a platform channel.
>
> The host listens on the platform channel, and receives the message. It
>   then calls into any number of platform-specific APIs – using the
>   native programming language – and sends back a response to the client,
>   the Flutter portion of your app.

Unfortunately, I don't see any [existing Flutter HealthKit](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=healthkit) but hopefully the available tools are enough to let you build your own bridge for HealthKit.

Brandon Donnelson's Video on [Creating a Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tErY3QWTZSA) may also help.

I am not sure if there are HealthKit alternatives to Android.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! :)
I've already made a simple battery app as per example of the tutorial of Flutter Platform Channels, so I've already experimented with that and was able to get the app to call native code to get the battery level of my iPhone. What I was still looking for was a way to get the amount of steps periodically or on change. I'll look into the resources you've provided.